# What happens if a point of a ringworld is at perigee?

Tags: physics, gravity, nonspherical-worlds, dyson-ring

Imagine the center of gravity of a ringworld is exactly at the center of mass of a star, there is no other massive objects so I wonder how do ringworld avoid drifting off and what happens if it has a point at perigee?

Answer (score 6):

You have noticed a fundamental problem with ringworlds: they are not stable. If they start to drift away from being centred on their sun, nothing naturally corrects that, and they will eventually collide with the star.

This [was noticed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringworld#Errors) soon after the publication of Niven's novel *Ringworld*. The sequel, *Ringworld Engineers*, added a set of attitude jets for corrections.

A more practical concept is the [Culture Orbital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Culture#Living_space), devised by Iain M Banks, which is a miniature ringworld, rotating once every 24 hours, which is in an ordinary orbit around its star, and does not enclose it. This still requires materials stronger than seem to be possible, but it's stable.